# hibernate : retrieving list-index value

Tags: hibernate

I work on a very old application, which uses Hibernate 3.6.10. I have an object called A, which contains a list of B objects, and this list is sorted with the "list-index" property. The problem is that those data have to be exported in a file, then imported, but since we export many others data at the same time, it's impossible to write/read the list of B objects in the right order : I need to export the "index" value, but it seems there is no way to retrieve it ! 
When I search on internet, it looks like I'm the only one on earth facing such a problem... I would like to try different things BUT it's not so easy : indeed; all my *.hbm.xml files are generated automatically by maven and androMDA using the datamodel (so I can't change it manually) AND I can't easily change this model since it was made with a very old version of a software for which we don't have anymore license. I tried to make changes in the XML file, but validation of the model failed.

So, here is my question : I think I should (also) declare my "list-index" property as an attribute in my association class between A and B, to have a getter on it (getIndex()), do you think it should be done like this ?

Thank you in advance for your advices !
Regards,
Pauline

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a list index column in the table.

```
 <list name="employees" table="employee"
        inverse="false" cascade="all">

            <key column="department_id"  />
        <list-index column="index" />

            <one-to-many class="com.hibernate.sample.Employee" />
        </list>
```

You don't have to define a `index` property in bean class, just add a **index** column in the Employee table and the collection `employees` should be `List`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have defined an "index" column like this, the problem is that there is no getIndex() method, and I need it. That's why I was wondered if I should also declare "index" as an integer attribute ...?